# Handling Optional get method inside Services

Tags: java, spring, service, option-type

I'm implementing an API but in my service layer I don't really know how to handle `.get()` of Optionals.

```
@Service
public class AttributedValueService {
    ...

    public AttributedValueDTO createAttributedValue(ActionDTO actionDTO) {
        Optional<RedeemableValue> redeemableValue = redeemableValueRepository.findRedeemableValueByProductId(actionDTO.getProductId());
        Optional<Value> value = valueRepository.findById(redeemableValue.get().getValue().getId());
        AttributedValue attributedValue = new AttributedValue(value.get(), actionDTO.getId(), actionDTO.getUserId());
        return new AttributedValueDTO(attributedValueRepository.save(attributedValue));
    }
}
```

My API receives a object and retrieves some other objects from the DB using info from that object and I want to make sure that a `ObjectNotFound` is returned when one of the `.get()` doesn't find a object.

Currently I'm thinking about using a `orElseThrow` on the find calls, something like that:

```
@Service
public class AttributedValueService {
    ...

    public AttributedValueDTO createAttributedValue(ActionDTO actionDTO) {
        RedeemableValue redeemableValue = redeemableValueRepository.findRedeemableValueByProductId(actionDTO.getProductId())
        .orElseThrow(() -> new ObjectNotFoundException("Id: "+redeemableValueDTO.getRedeemableValueId(),"Referred Redeemable Value could not be found"));

        Value value = valueRepository.findById(redeemableValue.get().getValue().getId())
        .orElseThrow(() -> new ObjectNotFoundException("Id: "+valueDTO.getValueId(),"Referred Value could not be found"));

        AttributedValue attributedValue = new AttributedValue(value.get(), actionDTO.getId(), actionDTO.getUserId());
        return new AttributedValueDTO(attributedValueRepository.save(attributedValue));
    }
}
```

Leaving exception handling for Spring, which returns a 404. But, is this the correct approach?

edit:
Fixed the Optional return of the `createAttributedValue` method, thanks for the tips.

Comment: There is no "silver bullet", different teams may solve this differently. I do not see anything inherently wrong with your approach.

Comment: Although it is a bit misleading that you return `Optional<AttributedValueDTO>`, since there's no execution that would return an empty optional in your suggested flow. You either return an actual object, or throw an exception.

Comment: I would rather go with using JSR-305 `@Nullable` or custom package-level`@NonnullByDefault` rather than using `Optional` to pretend there is "NPE safety" (no unnecessary `Optional` boxes, closure limitations, full "maybe optional vs definitely never null but still optional" coherency, etc etc etc).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as @Turing85 said, *there is no silver bullet*.

If you have a *RedeemableValueService* and *ValueService* you can let those classes handle the *Optional* instead of handling it at *AttributedValueService*

It would be something like:

```
@Service
public class AttributedValueService {
    ...

    public AttributedValueDTO createAttributedValue(ActionDTO actionDTO) {
        Value value = valueService.findByProductId(actionDTO.getProductId());
        AttributedValue attributedValue = new AttributedValue(value, actionDTO.getId(), actionDTO.getUserId());
        return new AttributedValueDTO(attributedValueRepository.save(attributedValue));
    }
}

@Service
public class ValueService {
    ...

    public Value findByProductId(IdType productId) {
        RedeemableValue redeemableValue = redeemableValueService.findByProductId(productId);
        return valueRepository.findById(redeemableValue.getValue().getId()).orElseThrow(YourException::new);
    }
}

@Service
public class RedeemableValueService {
    ...

    public RedeemableValue findByProductId(IdType productId) {
        return redeemableValueRepository.findRedeemableValueByProductId(productId).orElseThrow(YourException::new);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If i get you right, then you only have the use cases:

- either you find nothing, then an exception is thrown
- or you find something, then you return the object

Thus there is no need for an Optional because it will never be absent ^^ So why add this complexity?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand your question, your requirement is to check whether the object you are fetching from database is present or not if not then you want to throw some exception.
Here in Optional class we have one method isPresent() it will return true if Optional has some value or it will return false if not.

You can do like below:

```
@Service
public class AttributedValueService {
    ...

    public Optional<AttributedValueDTO> createAttributedValue(ActionDTO actionDTO) {
        Optional<RedeemableValue> redeemableValue = redeemableValueRepository.findRedeemableValueByProductId(actionDTO.getProductId());
if(redeemableValue.isPresent()){
        Optional<Value> value = valueRepository.findById(redeemableValue.get().getValue().getId());
if(value.isPresent()){
        AttributedValue attributedValue = new AttributedValue(value.get(), actionDTO.getId(), actionDTO.getUserId());
        return Optional.of(new AttributedValueDTO(attributedValueRepository.save(attributedValue)));}
else{
throw ObjectNotFoundException() //  custom exception
}
}
else{
throw ObjectNotFoundException() //  custom exception
}
    }
}
```

I don't understand your logic behind returning the Optional, because at each step we are checking for optional value then its not required.